# React Viro, click very long to fire in release

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm currently working on Ar app in react native, version 0.55, and react-viro, version,2.12.0. It's pokemon like app, where on the AR page, there's clickable item.
When the user clicks on it, it opens a modal.
In dev, (here is the complete commmand: adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && react-native run-android --variant=Ardebug),  it appaears right away.
But when we bunde it in  release mode, it takes at least one minute for the modal to appear.

The code for the page is :

```
 <ViroARScene onTrackingUpdated={this._onInitialized}>
        <ViroSpotLight
          innerAngle={5}
          outerAngle={45}
          direction={[0, -1, -0.2]}
          color="#ffffff"
          castsShadow={true}
          influenceBitMask={2}
          shadowMapSize={2048}
          shadowNearZ={2}
          shadowFarZ={5}
          shadowOpacity={0.7}
        />
        <ViroAmbientLight color="#ffffff" />
        <ViroNode ref={_setARNodeRef} onClick={this.tryGain}>
          <Viro3DObject
            position={[x, 0, z]}
            scale={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
            rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
            source={require(`${ROOT_3D_ASSET}chest/coffre_bois_obj.obj`)}
            resources={[

              require(`${ROOT_3D_ASSET}chest/coffre_bois_mtl.mtl`),
              require(`${ROOT_3D_ASSET}chest/wood.jpg`),
              require(`${ROOT_3D_ASSET}chest/wood2.jpg`),
              require(`${ROOT_3D_ASSET}chest/gold.jpg`)
            ]}
            onLoadStart={this._onLoadStart}
            onLoadEnd={this._onLoadEnd}
            onError={this._onError}
            lightReceivingBitMask={3}
            shadowCastingBitMask={2}
            type="OBJ"
          />
        </ViroNode>
      </ViroARScene>
```

and the function for click event is

```
tryGain = _ => {
    this.clickInterval=setInterval(() => (this.hasClicked = false), 500);// in case click, goes nowherer
    if (this.hasClicked) {
      return;
    }

    handleTryGain.call(this, this.props.activeGainPoiId, this.props.isDemo);
    this.hasClicked = true;

  };
```

It's the same code so I'm not sure why there's so much difference. Does anyone had the same problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out the problem looking at the log cat. Because of these props onLoadStart, onLoadEnd && onError, I was outputing  errors logs which overlowed the app, causing the delay. I fixed the problem by simply removing them in the Viro3DObject

```
<Viro3DObject ... same 
-> Deleted onLoadStart={this._onLoadStart} 
-> Deleted onLoadEnd={this._onLoadEnd} 
-> Deleted onError={this._onError} lightReceivingBitMask={3} shadowCastingBitMask={2} type="OBJ" />
```

Still has some errors, but that doesn't affect the app